# How to change the name of a collection of a custom class upon XML serialization?

Tags: c#, xml, xml-serialization

I'm serialising a List of a class and I'm not happy about the generated XML output.

```
[Serializable()]
public class Foo
{

    [XmlAttribute]
    public String Property1 { get; set; }

    public Foo() { }
}
```

---

```
public class Foo2
{
   List<Foo> _list = new List<Foo>()
   {
      new Foo(){ Property1="hello"}
    };

   // ...
   // code for serialization
   string path = "asdasd";
   using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create))
   {
     XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<Foo>));
     xs.Serialize(fs, _list);
     fs.Close();
   }
}
```

The output will result in:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ArrayOfFoo xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <Foo Property1="hello" />
</ArrayOfFoo>
```

Where must I set which attribute to alter the name of **ArrayOfFoo**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use the [proper constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f1wczcys.aspx):

```
var xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<Foo>), new XmlRootAttribute("foos"));
```

Also you could safely remove the `[Serializable]` attribute from your `Foo` class. This is for binary serialization and `XmlSerializer` ignores.